# MYSQL Query error WHERE id = $id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm creating and then editing a row in a table, however my edit mysql query in php is giving me an error that I can't figure out. Any help?

The creation query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO timelines (
id, event_name, event_date, date_created, attendee_count, attendee_names, maximum_attendees, creator_id, creator_name, price, thumbnail
) VALUES (
'{$timelineID}', '{$event_name}', '{$event_date}', '{$date_created}', '{$attendee_count}', '{$attendee_names}', '{$maximum_attendees}', '{$creator_id}', '{$creator_name}', '{$price}', '{$thumbnail}'
)";
```

The edit query:

```
$query = "UPDATE timelines SET 
event_name = '{$event_name}', 
event_date = '{$event_date}', 
maximum_attendees = '{$maximum_attendees}', 
price = '{$price}', 
thumbnail = '{$thumbnail}',
WHERE id = {$timelineID}";
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE id =' at line 8

Comment: I hope those variables are sanitized and escaped.

Comment: Hello, little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: why not first try `or die(mysql_error())` ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have an extra comma before the `WHERE` clause. just remove it and it will work fine.

```
thumbnail = '{$thumbnail}',
                          ^ here
WHERE ...
```

final query,

```
$query = "UPDATE timelines SET 
event_name = '{$event_name}', 
event_date = '{$event_date}', 
maximum_attendees = '{$maximum_attendees}', 
price = '{$price}', 
thumbnail = '{$thumbnail}'
WHERE id = {$timelineID}";
```

Your query is vulnerable with `SQL INJECTION`, please read the article below to learn how to protect from it.

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I tried that, now getting a different error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: do you have extra space between `thumbnail = '{$thumbnail}'` and 
`WHERE id = {$timelineID}"`?

Comment: check out the datatype of thumbnail

Comment: I figured it out. another careless mistake. it had to be WHERE id = '{$timelineID}'